# Draw image without repainting surfaces from other controls

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, controls

I have a transparent image to draw on a control called `Hex`. I hold it on `Form1`, and have a generator called `Map`.

Under `Paint(object, PaintEventArgs)` of `Hex` I draw the image:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(foo.Properties.Resources.h, ClientRectangle);
```

But it keeps repainting surfaces from other controls:

[image]

How can I avoid this?

For code of `Hex` and `Map`: http://pastebin.com/XsjKc3Yf

Comment: Share the rest of code, for example constructor of the control. It's unclear what you are asking now. Which part of the current image is a repaint of other controls? Is your control responsible to draw a single hexagon?

Comment: CreateGraphics is almost always a mistake.  Use the container's paint event and use the Graphic object from there.  This would work much better without a control for every hex since your controls are overlapping.

Comment: No I tried something else but it didn't apparently work. I had some other line xD

Comment: See my new answer; I had misread the question..

Comment: You are painting with rectangles. You probably need to use [FillPolygon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89sks199(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score -1):

I've went through the easiest way:

- Made `Hex` a special class.

  ```
  public class Hex
  {
      public Point Location;
      public Country Holder;

      public Hex(Country holder = null)
      {
          Holder = holder;
      }

      public void DrawMe(Graphics g)
      {
          g.DrawImage(Middle_Ages_Country.Properties.Resources.h, new Rectangle(Location, new Size(40, 40)));
      }
  }
  ```
- Edited `Map` class, and created a new method `DrawHexes` which will be called when necessary. Also used buffered graphics as it takes some time to draw it all.

  ```
  public Map(int rows, int columns, Form1 owner)
  {
      int x = 40, y = 40;
      // Create map
      for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
      {
          List<Hex> r = new List<Hex>();
          for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
          {
              Hex h = new Hex(null)
              {
                  Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y),
              };
              r.Add(h);
              x += 40;
          }
          Grid.Add(r);
          x -= columns * 40;
          x = (row % 2) * 20 + 20;
          y += 30;
      }
  }

  public void DrawHexes(Form1 owner)
  {
      BufferedGraphicsContext context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
      BufferedGraphics buf = context.Allocate(owner.CreateGraphics(), owner.ClientRectangle);

      buf.Graphics.Clear(Color.Red);

      foreach (List<Hex> row in Grid)
      {
          foreach (Hex h in row) h.DrawMe(buf.Graphics);
      }
      buf.Render();
  }
  ```

Comment: By giving up on the UserControls you have totally changed the premises. This does maybe help you and if you don't actually need controls to click or move etc by all means go for it __but certainly does not answer the original question.__

Comment: Sorry if I get too objective or mean. This answer fulfilled the question. I don't know much about graphics, so I stayed minimal.